Improve computational time and memory usage of the calculation of a large Matrix that has four loops [Python]
I want to calculate a Matrix G that its elements is a scalar and are calculated as:

I want to calculated this matrix for a large n > 10000, d>30. My code is below but it has a huge overhead and it still takes very long time.
How can I make this computation at the fastest possible way? Without using GPU and Minimize the memory usage.
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import Matern
from tqdm import tqdm
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

# Pre-flattened computation to minimize data transfer overhead
def precompute_differences(R, Z):
    n, d        = R.shape
    R_diff_flat = (R[:, None, :] - R[None, :, :]).reshape(n * n, d)
    Z_diff      = Z[:, None, :] - Z[None, :, :]
    return R_diff_flat, Z_diff

def compute_G_row(i, R_diff_flat, Z_diff, W, gamma_val, kernel, n, d):
    """
    Compute the i-th row for j >= i and store them in a temporary array.
    """
    row_values = np.zeros(n)
    for j in range(i, n):
        Z_ij   = gamma_val * Z_diff[i, j].reshape(1, d)
        K_flat = kernel(R_diff_flat, Z_ij)
        K_ij   = K_flat.reshape(n, n)
        row_values[j] = np.sum(W * K_ij)
    return i, row_values

def compute_G(M, gamma, R, Z, nu=1.5, length_scale=1.0, use_parallel=True):
    """
    Compute the G matrix with fewer kernel evaluations by exploiting symmetry:
    G[i,j] = G[j,i]. We only compute for j >= i, then mirror the result.
    """
    R = np.asarray(R)
    Z = np.asarray(Z)
    M = np.asarray(M).reshape(-1, 1)  # ensure (n,1)
    n, d = R.shape

    # Precompute data
    R_diff_flat, Z_diff = precompute_differences(R, Z)
    W = M @ M.T  # Weight matrix

    G = np.zeros((n, n))

    kernel = Matern(length_scale=length_scale, nu=nu)

    if use_parallel and n > 1:
        # Parallel computation
        results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(
            delayed(compute_G_row)(i, R_diff_flat, Z_diff, W, gamma, kernel, n, d)
            for i in tqdm(range(n), desc="Computing G matrix")
        )
    else:
        # Single-threaded computation
        results = []
        for i in tqdm(range(n), desc="Computing G matrix"):
            row_values = np.zeros(n)
            for j in range(i, n):
                Z_ij   = gamma * Z_diff[i, j].reshape(1, d)
                K_flat = kernel(R_diff_flat, Z_ij)
                K_ij   = K_flat.reshape(n, n)
                row_values[j] = np.sum(W * K_ij)
            results.append((i, row_values))

    # Sort and fill final G by symmetry
    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    for i, row_vals in results:
        for j in range(i, n):
            G[i, j] = row_vals[j]
            G[j, i] = row_vals[j]  # mirror for symmetry

    # Delete auxiliary variables to save memory
    del R_diff_flat, Z_diff, W, kernel, results

    # Optional checks
    is_symmetric = np.allclose(G, G.T, atol=1e-8)
    eigenvalues = np.linalg.eigvalsh(G)
    is_semi_positive_definite = np.all(eigenvalues >= -1e-8)
    print(f"G is semi-positive definite: {is_semi_positive_definite}")
    print(f"G is symmetric: {is_symmetric}")

    # Delete all local auxiliary variables except G to save memory
    local_vars = list(locals().keys())
    for var_name in local_vars:
        if var_name not in ["G"]:
            del locals()[var_name]

    return G

Toy Example
# Example usage:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    __spec__ = None
    n = 20
    d = 10
    gamma = 0.9
    R = np.random.rand(n, d)
    Z = np.random.rand(n, d)
    M = np.random.rand(n, 1)

    G = compute_G(M, gamma, R, Z, nu=1.5, length_scale=1.0, use_parallel=True)
    print("G computed with shape:", G.shape)


I suggest you do some profiling to find out which part of the calculation is taking a lot of the time, then focus on that. If you care about performance, why did you choose Python? Have you tried rewriting it in c or c++ for example? It uses some expensive functions which might already be well optimised so there's no guarantee it would be much faster.

It would help if you could provide a complete example so we can run/test the code.

Generally, in Python, to make codes faster, vectorization is the way to go but it tends to consume more memory (unless you operate on chunks which make the code far more complex and sub-optimal anyway). An alternative solution is to use tools like Cython/Numba, but here, it seems most of the time is in sklearn anyway so there is not much to do (more especially in kernel), unless you re-implement this more efficiently... If you do not want to do that (IDK how complex this is), then the only solutions seems to use another (faster) module or use another language (providing a lib for that).

@JérômeRichard I added a toy example. Thanks

Big-Oh notation will not be denied.  Matrix multiplication of two mxm matrices is O(m^3).   You can reduce that to O(m^2.8) or O(m^2.3) with symmetry, but that's the best you can do.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_matrix_multiplication

Thank you. As expected, most of the time is in the kernel computation. It mainly does a distance computation. While this computation can certainly be made a bit faster, I think the main problem is the algorithm complexity : O(n^4 d). This is not reasonable for n=10000 and d=30. This means approximately constant * 300_000_000_000_000_000 elementary floating-point operations. Even for a CPU reaching 1 TFlops, this would take several days. I do not see how to massively reduce the number of operations. An early stop can help a bit for non-symetric results (probably not the usual path though).
